# AWS Instance with 30 GB RAM, still running out of Memory and High CPU usage with small app?

Tags: apache2, ram, cpu, postgresql, ruby

We are on 30 GB AWS instance running a Ruby on Rails app using Passenger + Apache.

Though the App Postgres DB has millions of records, The DB size is few GB only. Now I am finding the server to always be on High Usage.

**What can I do to diagnose the issue or optimize the server to reduce CPU and Memory usage?** as the app keeps crashing due to high CPU or Memory usage with only 20 users online.

Here is the output of commands -

**uptime**

[image]

**sar -q**

[image]

**top**

[image]

**vmstat 10 6**

[image]

**iostat 2**

[image]

**ps -eo 'pcpu,%cpu,pid,comm' | grep -v '%CPU   PID COMMAND' | sort -n**
(last 20 rows)

[image]

**ps -eo 'rss,%mem,pcpu,%cpu,pid,comm' | grep -v '%CPU   PID COMMAND' | sort -n**

[image]